# HTML tags in Taxonomy Term Name

Tags: taxonomy-terms

[image: Filtered HTML settings]I'd like to emphasize a character in the Taxonomy Term Name field. Text format is Filtered HTML, but the name (=title) is being displayed like this:

`AK ORDERED SETS, <EM>N</EM>-UPLES, ORDERED ALGEBRAIC STRUCTURES`

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How you turned the name into filtered html ?

Comment: When editing a taxonomy term, you can choose "Text format": Filtered HTML, Full HTML, Plain text, PHP code.

Comment: But this is only affecting the term description, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Check the setup text format: Filtered HTML, here

```
admin/config/content/formats/[your_format]
```

The settings will filter the desired output.
Or just choose Full HTML (if configured properly) ;)

Comment: I don't see an option to allow html tags there.

Comment: Sorry .. here: admin/structure/taxonomy/[your_vocabulary]/display you can't select different options - true

Comment: This will allow html tags for term description. But the crucial question is your initial one: How do you get the taxonomy term name field to accept html tags?

Comment: Use the [title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module

Comment: Thank you! Ok, now I can select "Filtered HTML" for the name field, but the output is still ak: ordered sets, <em>n</em>-uples, ordered algebraic structures

Comment: check your filter settings of the 'filtered html' text format, or choose another text format, see my answer ;)

Comment: I checked the settings and they basically work, e.g. for menu link titles. In Full HTML, no tags are allowed.

Comment: I didn't mean "not allowed", but they are also not working.

Comment: have you updated the title field afterwards ? this could still come from the DB record

Comment: You mean cleared cache? Yes, I did.

Comment: no - I mean re-saving the term

Comment: Resaved it several times - no effect.

Comment: can you paste a screenshot of your text format's filter settings pls. and I did not get if it works with the full html format ?

Comment: done. full html doesn't work.